# httpfs could not be loaded: module could not be found

Tags: r, duckdb

I am trying to directly read JSON from the internet into a duckdb using R. I tried

```
library(duckdb)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), ":memory:")
stmt <- paste(
    "INSTALL httpfs; LOAD httpfs;",
    "INSTALL json;",
    "LOAD json;",
    "select * from read_json_auto('https://openalex.s3.amazonaws.com/data/authors/updated_date%3D2023-07-21/part_000.gz', format='newline_delimited', compression='gzip') limit 100;"
)
x <- dbGetQuery(con, stmt)
```

according to [this source](https://github.com/chrisgebert/open_alex_authors), but I get the error message

```
Error: IO Error: Extension "C:\Users\karsten.w\AppData\Roaming\R\data\R\duckdb\.duckdb\extensions\v0.8.1\windows_amd64_rtools\httpfs.duckdb_extension" could not be loaded: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I am on windows with R 4.2.1 and duckdb 0.8.1-3.

However, I can see a file named httpfs.duckdb_extension in the folder.

Comment: I posted an issue on https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/9112